# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de migrar una función privada de un form a una clase externa para poder accederla desde distintos forms?

Tags: c#, .net, formularios, google-cloud-firestore

soy nuevo en C# y me está constando un poco la sintaxis.

Quiero almacenar en una clase todas las funciones y métodos a **Firestore** en este caso que estoy utilizando.

Ahora mi pregunta puntual es cómo sería el código en una clase para mover esto que me está funcionando "ok" pero está en el form y no es lo óptimo.

```
private async Task<Users> ControlLogin(
        string name, string pass)
    {
        Query Qref = database.Collection("users").WhereEqualTo("usermail", name).WhereEqualTo("userpass", pass);

        QuerySnapshot snap = await Qref.GetSnapshotAsync();

        foreach (DocumentSnapshot docsnap in snap)
        {
            Users user = docsnap.ConvertTo<Users>();

            if (docsnap.Exists)           

                return user;              

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me respondo sólo por si a algun otro le sirve a futuro. 
Pude hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
 public class Funciones
    {
        static FirestoreDb _objetoLocal;

        public  FirestoreDb GetFirestoreObj() 
        {

        _objetoLocal =  FirestoreDb.Create("bingos-8xffaf1");
        return _objetoLocal;
        }


        // DEVUELBE UN OBJETO USER SI SE LOGUEA CORRECTAMENTE SINO NULL
        public async Task<Users> ControlLogin(string name, string pass)
        {
        Query Qref = _objetoLocal.Collection("users").WhereEqualTo("usermail", name).WhereEqualTo("userpass", pass);

        QuerySnapshot snap = await Qref.GetSnapshotAsync();
        foreach (DocumentSnapshot docsnap in snap)
        {
            Users user = docsnap.ConvertTo<Users>();

            if (docsnap.Exists)

                return user;

        }
        return null;

        }

    }
```

y llamo a eso de la siguiente manera ...

```
 private async void btLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Funciones myclase;
        myclase = new Funciones();

        Users user = await myclase.ControlLogin( TxMail.Text, TxPass.Text);
            if (user != null)
            {

                Form Formulario = new FormMain();
                Formulario.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Los datos ingresados no son válidos.");
            }

    }
```